# Unable to merger the value of 1 column that is in multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, database-administration

I am having trouble updating a column that is found in multiple tables with this script. I would like to use this to prevent duplicate UnitId's throughout the DB. I keep getting this error messages:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "Ppt${FA40D62B-B45A-46B2-A5C5-24BA8E5B6318}". The conflict occurred in
>   database "MQS-demo", table "dbo.Unit", column 'UnitID'.

and

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "Ppt${FA40D62B-B45A-46B2-A5C5-24BA8E5B6318}". The conflict occurred in
>   database "MQS-demo", table "dbo.Ppt", column 'UnitID'.

Here is the query

```
declare @oldUnitID as int=0;
declare @newUnitID as int=0;
declare @temp as TABLE
(
     bincode nvarchar(200),
     cnt     int
)

insert into @temp
select bincode, Count(*)
from   unit
group  by bincode -- HAVING count(*)=2

--select * from @temp

WHILE (SELECT Count(*) from   @temp) > 0 BEGIN

      DECLARE @bincodetodedup as nvarchar(200);

      select top(1) @bincodetodedup = bcode
      from   @temp;

      DECLARE @unitstodedup as TABLE
      (
           unitid int,
           num    int
      )

      insert into @unitstodedup
      select distinct UnitID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY unitid) as num
      from   unit
      where  bincode = @bincodetodedup
      order  by unitid

      WHILE (SELECT Count(*) from @unitstodedup) > 0 BEGIN
            SELECT TOP(1) @oldUnitID = Unitid
            from   @unitstodedup
            where  num = 1

            SELECT TOP(1) @newUnitID = Unitid
            from   @unitstodedup
            where  num > 1

            update Compatibility
            set    UnitID = @newUnitID
            where  UnitID = @oldUnitID

            update PriceList
            set    UnitID = @newUnitID
            where  UnitID = @oldUnitID

            update Project
            set    UnitID = @newUnitID
            where  UnitID = @oldUnitID

            update ProjectNum
            set    UnitID = @newUnitID
            where  UnitID = @oldUnitID

            update Rate
            set    UnitID = @newUnitID
            where  UnitID = @oldUnitID

            update Resolve
            set    UnitID = @newUnitID
            where  UnitID = @oldUnitID

            update Services
            set    UnitID = @newUnitID
            where  UnitID = @oldUnitID

            update TrainingDate
            set    UnitID = @newUnitID
            where  UnitID = @oldUnitID

            update Form
            set    UnitID = @newUnitID
            where  UnitID = @oldUnitID

            update Ppt
            set    UnitID = @newUnitID
            where  UnitID = @oldUnitID

            --update Unit set UnitID=@newUnitID where UnitID=@oldUnitID
            update Manager
            set    UnitID = @newUnitID
            where  UnitID = @oldUnitID
      END

      DELETE FROM unit
      where  unitid = @oldUnitID

      DELETE TOP(1) from @unitstodedup

      DELETE TOP(1) from @temp
END
```

Comment: Despite the error your code has several major flaws in it. You repeatedly select top 1 with no order by. As such you have now way of knowing which row will be returned (or deleted). Your inner loop is also an endless loop because nothing inside that loop delete from the unitstodedup table variable. The biggest issue I see though is that this entire nested looping construct should be rewritten as a set based approach and forget the looping entirely.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't catch that it was an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do not you do the delete at the end with the variables you are assigning?

```
    DELETE from @temp where bcode = @bincodetodedup
    DELETE from @unitstodedup where num=1
    DELETE from @unitstodedup where num>1
```